# How to filter posts by a specific user in Django?

Tags: django, django-users

I want to set up a newsfeed website for my college. There must be tabs in the navbar like **Current News, Literary Society, Clubs, Placement News** etc. How do I go about making those tabs functional?

For example:

**Current News** will be the homepage, 
**Literary Society** will show the posts by a user named 'Literary Society' and so on.

Comment: You need to show your code so far.

Comment: update your question with related code of `models.py` and `views.py` and `urls.py`